# Flashlight app for Android that can adjust the intensity of the camera's flash (light)

Tags: android, user-interface, camera, flash, sport

Please recommend a flashlight app for Android that allows the user to *vary the intensity of the camera's flash* that is used for the light.

There are scores (hundreds?) of apps in the Google Play store that claim "brightest flashlight" and other nonsense, but all they do is toggle the flash on/off.

Many Samsung phones (such as the Samsung Galaxy 6) let the user adjust the intensity of the flash used for the flashlight by long-pressing on the flashlight icon in Android's `Quick Settings` panel.  That works well if you want to launch the flashlight via the tiny quick settings button, and don't mind a clunky UI.

I'm looking for a **flashlight app** that can do the same thing.

Any price is fine, but gratis is a plus.  Prefer no ads and open-source, but neither is a requirement.

*Related: [Technique to adjust the camera flash intensity without using Android's Quick Settings panel](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234365/technique-to-adjust-the-camera-flash-intensity-without-using-androids-quick-set)*

Answer (score 1):

***Disclosure: I am the author of FlashDim***

You can check out FlashDim, for Android 13 and later:
https://github.com/cyb3rko/flashdim
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyb3rko.flashdim
https://f-droid.org/packages/com.cyb3rko.flashdim/

---

Starting with Android 13, it's possible to control multiple brightness levels of the flashlight.
This app uses this new API and lets you control all brightness levels of your phone if supported.

And be warned, there are many apps that don't have hardware support for this feature, a list of phones I know of is available here:
https://github.com/cyb3rko/flashdim#exluded-devices-play-store--unsupported-devices

---

[image][image]

Comment: Welcome, and thank you Cyb3rKo!  To clarify, your app requires Android 13 to control multiple brightness levels, and on other versions of Android, it will simply toggle the light on and off?

Comment: Also, just FYI, our community has a requirement that when anyone recommends an app with which they have affiliation that they disclose that affiliation.  I'll add that disclosure for you so you can see what it looks like (nice and simple).

Comment: Not exactly. You can only install it on Android 13 and above. Most modern devices support dimming the flashlight, but still there are some, that don't. On these devices then you can only use the other features of the app (SOS, Morse, Interval).

Comment: And I'm sorry, dind't know that detail. Thanks for adding it to my comment

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications regarding Android level compatibility.  And no problem not knowing about the affiliation disclosure requirement.  I figured you simply didn't know, so no harm done at all.  Thanks for writing this app, for posting about it here, and again, welcome to our community!

Answer (score 0):

**[Flashy](https://github.com/Crazy-Marvin/Flashy)** should meet your requirements:

- **allows the user to vary the intensity of the camera's flash:** "this flashlight app allows you to control the brightness of the mobile flashlight"
- **Prefer no ads and open-source:** get it [at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/rocks.poopjournal.flashy/)
- **but neither is a requirement:** get it at the toy shop, ahem, [at Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rocks.poopjournal.flashy) and have your install tracked
- **Any price is fine, but gratis is a plus:** ++

Note I haven't used the app myself, so I just went by the app's description. Here is a screenshot from it's F-Droid listing:

[image]

You see it can use either your screen or your flashlight, and has a brightness control. As usual, you can find alternative candidates in [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/domestic_tools#group_1056)

Comment: On a Redmi Note 9S, with Flashy, I am not able to change the intensity of the camera flash, only the screen.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 maybe take a look at the linked app listing and check if one of the other candidates works? As I wrote, I haven't tried any of them – so this might be a limitation of the app, or of your device.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not possible unless the brand allows it. Samsung allows it and has a built-in method for changing the flashlight intensity. Maybe other phones do too, for which the other answer (Flashy) could work... But for most other Android phones, it's not customizable (and that makes sense probably, it could damage the flashlight module if it doesn't support a wide range of intensities)